# BASH, cat Buffer

Tags: bash, queue, buffer, pipe, cat

```
cat report.txt | sed 's/<\/li>/<\/li> \n/g' > report.txt
```

This obviously results in an empty file.

Is there a mechanism that allows you to store the data before processing it or store the output until the command has finished executing and then write the file?

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)#Implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29#Implementation):

"...a receiving program may only be able to accept 100 bytes per second, but no data is lost. Instead, the output of the sending program is held in a queue. When the receiving program is ready to read data, the operating system sends its data from the queue, then removes that data from the queue."

Sounds like there should be a simple trick to load this into a queue instead of writing it immediately to file, then unload it after the command has finished?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is editing [*in place*](http://joemaller.com/823/quick-note-about-seds-edit-in-place-option/):

```
sed -i 's/<\/li>/<\/li> \n/g' report.txt
```

Comment: This would work.

I figured out that:

`echo "$( cat [file] | cmd1 | cmd2 )" > [file]`

Also works, because the subshell executes first.